# Unsafe Object binding Checkmarx

Tags: java, hibernate, security, java-8, checkmarx

I am getting alert in Checkmarx scan saying Unsafe object binding in the saveAll() call.
The exact words in checkmarx are -

```
The columnConfigSet at src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\moa\controller\ConfigController.java in line 45 may unintentionally allow setting the value of saveAll in setColumnsConfig, in the object src\main\java\com\ge\digital\oa\moa\service\ConfigService.java at line 170.
```

Any idea how to rewrite the code , so that the checkmarx stops complaining.

My code:

```
@PutMapping("/columns")
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public void setColumnsConfig(@RequestBody(required=true) ColumnConfigSetDto columnConfigSet) {
    service.setColumnsConfig(columnConfigSet);
}
```

---

```
public void setColumnsConfig(ColumnConfigSetDto columnConfigSet) {

    String userId = columnConfigSet.getUserId();
    String viewName = columnConfigSet.getViewName();
    
    List<ColumnConfig> configs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (ColumnConfigDto colConfig : columnConfigSet.getColumns()) {            
        
        // build a db config row only for the visibility property for now
        ColumnConfigId confId = new ColumnConfigId();
        
        confId.setUserId(userId);
        confId.setViewName(viewName);
        confId.setKey(colConfig.getKey());
        confId.setProperty("visible");
        
        ColumnConfig conf = new ColumnConfig();
        conf.setColumnConfigId(confId);
        conf.setValue(colConfig.getIsVisible() ? "true" : "false" );
    
        configs.add(conf);
    }
    
    if (!configs.isEmpty()) {
        configRepo.saveAll(configs);
    }


    
    }
```

---

Below are my DTO Objects which is used in this code :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ColumnConfigSetDto {

    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private String userId;
    
    @JsonProperty("viewName")
    private String viewName;
    
    @JsonProperty("columns")
    private List<ColumnConfigDto> columns;
}
```

---

Below are my DTO code which is used in this

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ColumnConfigDto {

    @JsonProperty("key")
    private String key;
    
    @JsonProperty("label")
    private String label;
    
    @JsonProperty("isVisible")
    private Boolean isVisible;
    
    @JsonProperty("position")
    private Integer position;
    
    @JsonProperty("isSortable")
    private Boolean isSortable;
    
    @JsonProperty("isHideable")
    private Boolean isHideable;
    
}
```

Comment: may be I am not a native English speaker, but I have no idea what that error messages is trying to allude. :|

Comment: I am also confused by the wording..but the category of vulnerability falls under Unsafe_object_binding category..and what I understand is an attacker can put any value in the Request body ColumnConfigSetDto and that data is directly saved in the DB by the saveAll() method and this might corrupt the database

Comment: I see, that somehow makes sense then. So you need to add `@Validated` may be? To have some proper validations in place?

Comment: So instead of iterating over `columnConfigSet.getColumns()` you have to iterate over a list of known identifiers and look them up in `columnConfigSet`, to only process those known columns.

Comment: Thnx @Holger I have given the dtos too..how do I validate the identifiers in the `columnConfigSet` ..is there any easy way?

Comment: I even tried to convert the dto to an entity via a converter ,and loop through that entity in the service class, but its still giving the same error in the converter too eg. whenever I am giving columnConfigSet.getxxx() its giving the alert

Comment: I’m not familiar with checkmarx. I was just building on your assumption in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568827/unsafe-object-binding-checkmarx#comment121180867_68568827) and explained how to address the issue described there. Unfortunately, I don’t know whether this truly is checkmarx’ concern or what code pattern it is checking.

Comment: I know its late... you can try adding validations to variables defeined in class before using them.

Comment: Please post the solution if you could crack it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for Unsafe object binding reported by cherkmarx in Java.
It's not a graceful approach and only fix this vulnerability.

**Remove all setter methods for boxed fields in each requestbody bean.**
Since `@JsonProperty` could support deserialization capbility, no need to add setter manually.

If you need setter for request body bean indeed, you can use reflaction way instead.
`FieldUtils.writeField(columnConfigDto , "isVisible", true, true);`

```
public class ColumnConfigDto {
    // Ensure @JsonProperty existed on each field 
    @JsonProperty("key")
    private String key;

    @JsonProperty("isVisible")
    private Boolean isVisible;

    @JsonProperty("list")
    private List list;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Boolean getVisible() {
        return isVisible;
    }
    
// Remove boxed type field     
//    public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
//        isVisible = visible;
//    }

    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }

// Remove boxed type field   
//    public void setList(List list) {
//        this.list = list;
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue occurs due to @RequestBoby as per spring documentation but there is no issue for @RequestParam. if we bind request body to object without @RequestBody, this issue is not occurred.

`HttpServletRequest request;`

`mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), Product.class);`

Answer (score 0):

The error is also thrown if data is set to an object annotated with `@RequestBody`.

```java
requestBodyVariable.setAdditionalValue(valueFromRequestParamOrPathVariable); 
// This setter call should not be used
```

Instead, use a user-defined variable for storing the value from request param, header or path variable in its place:

```java
service.callServiceMethod(requestBodyVariable, valueFromRequestParamOrPathVariable);
```